# Incrementing and decrementing dates

Tags: sql

There is a transaction table , having date of transaction.
I want to increment date by 20 years and then save it
and then I want to decrement it by 20 years(original date).

Need help!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO :) StackOverflow users are not there to do everything in your place. You should edit your question and explain what you've tried so far. It will show that you made some efforts to look for answers by yourself first : [How do I ask a good question ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATE_ADD function.

```
E.g : DATE_ADD(date, expr type)

DATE_ADD('2016-07-02', INTERVAL 20 YEAR)
```

For more info and expr type : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp